# Riemann tensor in linearized theory of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, curvature, linearized-theory

Here I present some approximations to Christoffel, Riemann, Ricci tensors when the following perturbed metric is taken into account $g_{\mu \nu} \approx \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu} + \mathcal{O}(h_{\mu \nu})^2$.

Christoffel symbols
$$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu} \approx \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\lambda\rho}(h_{\rho\nu , \mu}+h_{\mu \rho , \nu}-h_{\mu \nu , \rho})$$

Ricci tensor
$$R_{\mu \nu} \approx \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu, \alpha} - \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \alpha, \nu}$$

Riemann tensor
$$R^{\sigma}_{\hspace{3mm}\mu \nu \rho} \approx \frac{1}{2}(h^{\sigma}_{\hspace{3mm}\rho, \nu \mu}+h_{\mu \nu \rho}^{\hspace{3mm}\sigma}-h_{\mu \rho \nu}^{\hspace{3mm}\sigma}-h_{\hspace{3mm}\nu, \rho \mu}^{\sigma})$$

It is almost straightforward to see Christoffel symbols and Ricci tensor. However, the second and third terms presented in the Riemann tensor don't look natural. It was given in the lecture notes on gravitational waves. Any correction/link to above form is highly appreciated. What I would expect to see (just by look) is

$$R^{\sigma}_{\hspace{3mm}\mu \nu \rho} \approx \frac{1}{2}(h^{\sigma}_{\hspace{3mm}\rho, \nu \mu}+h_{\mu \nu ,\rho}^{\hspace{3mm},\sigma}-h_{\mu \rho , \nu}^{\hspace{3mm},\sigma}-h_{\hspace{3mm}\nu, \rho \mu}^{\sigma})$$

Comment: If your question is, "is there a typo" I'd say yes.  No one can give you a correction link unless you provide a link to these notes.  Are they notes you found on line, or took in class?  I'd say just look up the derivation in MTW, or Wald, any classic text on GR will have the full derivation and the correct equations.  Though I can say from personal experience that I have NEVER read a text or article that didn't have some typesetting errors in it.  This is why we need to derive.

Comment: They were pp presentations prepared by a professor at uni and these equations were given without derivations. I guess I'm gonna check the books you listed, I will derive by myself at worst.

Comment: There are clearly commas missing, you are correct about that.  The question is where do they go.  O don't think you need upper commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a confirmation, yes, there are two missing commas. The linearized Riemann tensor to first order in the metric perturbation is

$${R_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }} = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {{\partial _\beta }{\partial _\mu }{h_{\alpha \nu }} + {\partial _\alpha }{\partial _\nu }{h_{\beta \mu }} - {\partial _\alpha }{\partial _\mu }{h_{\beta \nu }} - {\partial _\beta }{\partial _\nu }{h_{\alpha \mu }}} \right].$$

Then, you can also check this

$${R^\sigma }_{\beta \mu \nu } = {\eta ^{\alpha \sigma }}{R_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu }} = ...,$$

which confirms your guess.